# Fetch data from OMDb API with Alamofire (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, ios10

So, i'm trying to create an iOS app (i'm a beginner) that search a movie on IMDB (using OMDb API with Alamofire). The language is swift 3.

After reading a lot of tutorials I did two methods to connect to the API:

```
func searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> ()) {

let urlByName: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(imdbTitle)&type=movie"

//returns a list of movies that contains the title searched
Alamofire.request(urlByName).responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):
            let moviesJSON = value
            completionHandler(moviesJSON as? Dictionary<String, Any>)

        case .failure(_):
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}

func getMovieFromJson(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, String>) -> ()) {

let urlById: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID)"

    Alamofire.request(urlById).responseJSON {
        response in

        if let moviesJSON = response.result.value {
            completionHandler(moviesJSON as! Dictionary<String, String>)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I did my Movie class and get stuck in my MovieDAO class (code above):

```
class Movie {

let poster: String?
let title: String?
let runtime: String?
let genre: String?
let director: String?
let actors: String?
let plot: String?
let released: String?
let imdbID: String?
let imdbRating: String?

init(poster: String?, title: String?, runtime: String?, genre: String?, director: String?, actors: String?, plot: String?, released: String?, imdbID: String?, imdbRating: String?) {

    //checking if is nil

    if let isPoster = poster {
        self.poster = isPoster
    } else {
        self.poster = nil
    }

    if let isTitle = title {
        self.title = isTitle
    } else {
        self.title = nil
    }

    if let isGenre = genre {
        self.genre = isGenre
    } else {
        self.genre = nil
    }

    if let isRuntime = runtime {
        self.runtime = isRuntime
    } else {
        self.runtime = nil
    }

    if let isDirector = director {
        self.director = isDirector
    } else {
        self.director = nil
    }

    if let isActors = actors {
        self.actors = isActors
    } else {
        self.actors = nil
    }

    if let isPlot = plot {
        self.plot = isPlot
    } else {
        self.plot = nil
    }

    if let isReleased = released {
        self.released = isReleased
    } else {
        self.released = nil
    }

    if let isImdbID = imdbID {
        self.imdbID = isImdbID
    } else {
        self.imdbID = nil
    }

    if let isImdbRating = imdbRating {
        self.imdbRating = isImdbRating
    } else {
        self.imdbRating = nil
    }
  }
}
```

I have a table view controller with a search bar and a table view, when the user type the movie title I would like to show the results in my table view.

How can I make the result of my search bar functions be the variable that my MovieDAO will receive? (Sorry if I sad something wrong, feel free to correct me, please)

My search bar test to get user's text:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange imdbTitle:String) {
    print("Movie typed: \(imdbTitle)")
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    print("Movie searched: \(searchBar.text!)")
}
```

Any orientation, explanation, tutorial indication? Every help will be welcome!

Comment: use predicate to find your title from your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ObjectMapper to map the objects https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper. And also use AlamofireObjectMapper to retrieve data https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper .you can get the tutorials from these links.

Alamofire.request(url,method: .yourmethod).validate().responseArray{ (response:DataResponse<[yourObjectMapperClass]>) in
}

Comment: I did that, but I'm a little confused with nested objects. Could you give me a help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687567/get-value-from-array-objects-with-alamofireobjectmapper-objectmapper-swift-io